# Arithmetic operation on array aggregation in postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, types, aggregate-functions

I have 2 questions regarding array_agg in postgres

1) I have a column which is of type array_agg. I need to divide each of the element of the array_agg by a constant value. Is it possible. I checked http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html, but could not find any reference to any arithmetic operations on array_agg.

Edit:
An example of the desired operation.

```
select array_agg(value)/2 from some_table
```

Here, I create an array of the column `value` from the table `some_table` and I have to divide each of the column by `4`

2) Is it possible to use coalesce in array_agg. In my scenario, there may be cases wherein, the array_agg of a column may result in a NULL array. Can we use coalesce for array_agg ?

Example:

```
select coalsece(array_agg(value1), 0)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dividing is probably simper than you thought:

```
SELECT array_agg(value/2)
FROM ...
```

However, what `value/2` does exactly depends on the data type. If value is an `integer`, fractional digits are truncated. To preserve fractional digits use `value/2.0` instead. The fractional digit forces the calculation to be done with [`numeric`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) values.

`COALESCE` won't make any difference *outside* the array. Either there are no rows, then you get no result at all ('no row'), or if there are, you get an array, possibly with `NULL` elements. But the value of the array itself is never `NULL`.

To replace individual `NULL` values with `0`:

```
SELECT array_agg(coalesce(value/2.0, 0))
FROM ...
```